# Function to call the attachment image from post

Tags: images, attachments, plugin-gravity-forms

Hey everyone, I can't se the image of the post (it is attached through gravity form as a post-image) with this function I see the missing image icon with the title and the working link but no thumbnail image.? It is suposed to be more or less ( authors last 2 posts in the widget area) I suspect the problem is here :

```
$output .= '<img src="' .  wp_attachment_is_image( $post_id ) . '" alt="" />';
```

So please help me out :D

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
global $authordata, $post;

$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'author' => $authordata->ID, 
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 2 ) );

$output = '<ul class="post_related">' . "\n";
foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
    $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '" title="' . 
apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '">';
    $output .= '<img src="' .  wp_attachment_is_image( $post_id ) . '" alt=""
/>';
    $output .= '</a></li>' . "\n";
}
$output .= '</ul>';

return $output;
}
```

Comment: wp-attachment_is_image only tells you if the attachment is an image - so it returns true or false.

Comment: any idea how to retrieve image from post than instead of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand right that you mean featured thumbnail image for a post and not just any attached image?

See [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) function and your usage will be something like this:

```
$output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $authors_post->ID );
```

Comment: No I mean the image that was attached to the post via gravity form post image field. It is not a featured image, it's an attached image!!!

Comment: @jimilesku I am not familiar with gravity forms, is _attached to the post via gravity form post image field_ same as native WP attachment or not?

Comment: This code does not work :(

Comment: I think it is...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) directly in your current code:

```
$output .= '<img src="' .  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ) . '" alt="" />';
```

Or you can use [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) in *place* of your current code:

```
$output .= wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size );
```

Note that in both cases you will have to retrieve the attachment ID in some manner. The most direct method will probably be [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), e.g.:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
) );
```

Which will return an array of attachment objects.